# WSDL calling from Android causes NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, web-services, wsdl

Here is this sample code (MainActivity):

```
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/CelsiusToFahrenheit";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "CelsiusToFahrenheit";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx";
TextView tv;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    request.addProperty("Celsius", "32");

    SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapSerializationEnvelope.VER11);
    soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
    soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try {
        aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
        SoapPrimitive resultString = (SoapPrimitive)soapEnvelope.getResponse();
        tv.setText("Status: " + resultString);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        tv.setText("Problem: " + e.toString());
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
```

...

When I run this code I got this message Problem: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException. 
In the manifest.xml added the

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

line. 
[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xidgpdmoy36njju/WebServiceClient.zip)
is the whole android project.

Does someone have any idea how to change this code?
Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

[NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) throws when you are performing network operation on its main thread.

So you have to run you network operations in [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

You can call AsyncTask like below

```
new SerializationConnection().execute(URL);
```

then `SerializationConnection class`

```
class SerializationConnection extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            request.addProperty("Celsius", "32");

            SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapSerializationEnvelope.VER11);
            soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
            soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE(urls[0]);
            aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
            SoapPrimitive resultString = (SoapPrimitive)soapEnvelope.getResponse();
            return "Status: " + resultString;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "Problem: " + e.toString();
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        tv.setText(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear Hariharan,
I changed my code as you suggested, and it,s works!
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

This exception is thrown when an android application attempts to perform a network operation on its main thread. You must run your code in AsyncTask. Your code will look something like this
You can declare resultString as an instance variable

```
class SoapTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    private Exception exception;

        @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        try {
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            request.addProperty("Celsius", "32");

            SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapSerializationEnvelope.VER11);
            soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
            soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

            try {
                aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
                resultString = "Status:" + (SoapPrimitive)soapEnvelope.getResponse(); 
            } catch (Exception e) {
                resultString = "Problem:" + e.toString();
            }
        }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
         tv.setText("Status: " + resultString);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making a server call in main thread.if your target version is 9

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

For Better way try to use AsynTask